# Im getting a "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error after updating Xcode to version 14.3

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Im trying to archive so I can update my testflight version but I keep getting interrupted with this error. please help!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo", referenced from:
      _GDTCCTConstructLogRequest in libGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.a(GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this a screenshot of the error message
[image]